# Save ssh connection pantheon-files

Tags: pantheon-files, ssh

I'm able to connect to an ssh server through pantheon-files, the problem is that I'd like to save this connection somewhere so that I'm able to click on the saved connection and it will automatically connect without asking me info everytime.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try bookmarking the root folder on the server (Use the folder context menu).  Close the connection and click on the bookmark.  When asked for your password select "Keep for ever".  Note: You can rename the bookmark to whatever is most helpful for you.  Unfortunately, at the moment, you cannot move outside of the "Personal bookmarks" section.

Comment: That's great my friend, thank you very much! Stupidly I didn't think it