# How to manage logins, and cash information of "Connect to Server" in ElementaryOS?

Tags: pantheon-files, ssh

How can I edit and manage my login credentials I entered to connect to sftp, ssh servers using the default ELementaryOS File Explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no in built facility to do this securely at present. But the answer to [Save ssh connection pantheon-files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13770/save-ssh-connection-pantheon-files?rq=1) shows how to use bookmarks to make reconnection more convenient.  Note using this method the user name and address of the server are not encrypted although the password is stored securely by the system.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's very important to support this feature in the coming update cause it's really boring to type in the credentials every time.